Append filename if already exists using ADF
I am uploading file/s from SFTP to ADLS synapse. If the filename is already exists in adls, I want it to append or increment.
Ex.
Employee_213.parquet (in ADLS synapse)
And I am uploading with the same filename, my expected filename will be:
Employee_213_1.parquet
what i have tried is just copy the file/s from sftp to adls/edl synapse. but when i tried to upload same filename, it overwrites the previous file, no append happened.

The SFTP is an on-prem Or normal one?

the sftp is an on-prem.

Can you provide any approach that you have tried so far? pipeline flow? or any error that you got?

what i have tried is just copy the file/s from sftp to adls/edl synapse. but when i tried to upload same filename, it overwrites the previous file, no append happened.

Did you try the approach that I have given in below answer? Is your issue still not resolved?

In this case, you need an Intermediate location. If you want to use a ADLS location as an intermediate location, you can use Union transformation in the dataflow. If you want to avoid using Dataflow, you can use any SQL database as temporary location.
First check whether the source file already exists or not in the target location. You can pass your source file name to Get meta data activity as parameter and use exists property. Then, take an if activity to check the result of this. If it's false, take a copy activity in the False activities of if, to directly copy the file to target. If its' true, Follow any of the below approaches.
Using SQL database:
This approach requires 3 copy activities inside the True activities if if.

First copy activity will be used to copy the target file data to a new SQL table (Use auto create table option).

Second copy activity is to copy the SFTP file data to the created SQL table. Here, if you only want to append the data, you can directly select insert option in the copy activity sink. If you want incremental loading, you should have a key column and you should know that column name prior to this copy activity and you need to use that in the copy activity sink like below. Give that column names as the dynamic expression @createarray(<column_name>).


Third copy activity is to copy the result data in the same SQL table to the required target table in ADLS.


In this approach, you need to use dataset parameters and pass the required file names and table name accordingly.
Union transformation:
In this approach, you can only append the new data to the old data, but incremental loading (Upsert) is not possible.
Here Dataflow currently does not support on-premises connectors.
So, First take a copy activity and copy the source file from SFTP to a temporary location in the ADLS. Now, take a dataflow activity and pass your file name as a parameter. In the dataflow, take 2 sources (one is a target file, and another is the source file in temporary location) and use Union transformation on both. In the sink, give your target ADLS file.
You can go through this SO answer to know more about this approach.

Usually it is better to append datetime to the filename when you get the same file.
If you want to generate the sequence number in the filename here you go
The pipeline design look like below


Get Metadata activity(Get Metadata Source) to read the source file from file share and configure it as shown below


For Each activity
The for each loop through the source file from the previous get metadata activity.
The for each items expression under setting tab shown below


@activity('Get Metadata Source').output.childItems

Under for each activity tab add the below activities


Lookup activity
This activity will call a stored procedure and increment the sequence for filename and return the filename for the destination.

Create a table using below script
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileNameSequence](
    [OriginalFileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FileNameSequence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OriginalFileName] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Stored procedure script
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFileNameSequence
(
    @FileName varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM dbo.FileNameSequence
        WHERE OriginalFileName = @FileName
    )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.FileNameSequence
        SET 
        SequenceNo = SequenceNo+1
        WHERE OriginalFileName = @FileName

        SELECT SUBSTRING(OriginalFileName,1,CHARINDEX('.',OriginalFileName)-1)+'_'+Cast(SequenceNo As varchar)+SUBSTRING(OriginalFileName,CHARINDEX('.',OriginalFileName),len(OriginalFileName)) AS FileName FROM dbo.FileNameSequence WHERE OriginalFileName = @FileName;

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.FileNameSequence([OriginalFileName],  [SequenceNo])
        VALUES(@FileName,0)

        SELECT OriginalFileName AS FileName FROM dbo.FileNameSequence WHERE OriginalFileName = @FileName;

    END

    
END
GO

Configure the lookup activity to call the stored procedure which return the filename for destination as shown below


Copy activity
Copy activity take the filename output and move the file to destination

Source settings

Sink Setting
The sink parameter pmFile expression is
@activity('GetFileName').output.firstRow.FileName


I tested the initial run with 2 input files the pipeline ran sucessfully and copied the file as it is as there is no file in the destination.

the table which generate the sequence would look like this

the Source(before execution) and destination(after execution) for initial run shown as below

For the next run i added 2 same file and 1 different file
the table data look like this now

the Source(before execution) and destination(after execution) for next run shown as below

For the subsequent run same files with same name will keep on appending the incremental sequence number.
Also please add a error logic if any error happened during file movement decrease the sequence counter for that file.
Hope this will work for you.
thanks
